# How do I get a methods parameters as IJavaElements in Eclispe jdt 3.6?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

For compatibility reasons, I have to adapt my Eclipse Plugin from JDT 3.7 to 3.6. Unfortunately, the old version doesn't seem to have the handy .getParameters() method yet.

I need to display an ElementTreeSelectionDialog to the user, allowing him to browse through methods of a class and select a parameter of a method. For this, I have written a ITreeContentProvider with this straightforward getChildren - method:

```
public Object[] getChildren(Object paramObject) {       
        if(paramObject instanceof ICompilationUnit){
            ICompilationUnit icu = (ICompilationUnit) paramObject;
            try {
                return icu.getAllTypes()[0].getMethods();
            } catch (JavaModelException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(paramObject instanceof IType){
            IType type = (IType) paramObject;
            try {
                return type.getMethods();
            } catch (JavaModelException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(paramObject instanceof IMethod){
            IMethod method = (IMethod) paramObject;
            try {
                return method.getParameters();
            } catch (JavaModelException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I'd like to stick to the interfaces to be able to use the JavaUILabelProvider, which displays everything with proper icons, Signatures etc.

So the tricky part is to either create valid LocalVariable objects from the parameters or some other valid IJavaElement implementation, which would be displayed properly by JavaUILabelProvider.

I have tried creating an array of LocalVariable[], but this doesn't really work out, since I can't find any way to get the necessary position markers and Annotation objects for the elements...